# Appending to boost::filesystem::path

Tags: c++, boost

I have a certain `boost::filesystem::path` in hand and I'd like to append a string (or path) to it.

```
boost::filesystem::path p("c:\\dir");
p.append(".foo"); // should result in p pointing to c:\dir.foo
```

The only overload `boost::filesystem::path` has of `append` wants two `InputIterator`s.

My solution so far is to do the following:

```
boost::filesystem::path p2(std::string(p.string()).append(".foo"));
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>


int main() {
  boost::filesystem::path p (__FILE__);

  std::string new_filename = p.leaf() + ".foo";
  p.remove_leaf() /= new_filename;
  std::cout << p << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Tested with 1.37, but *leaf* and *remove_leaf* are also documented in [1.35](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html).  You'll need to test whether the last component of *p* is a filename first, if it might not be.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is better than what I currently do but I'll accept it anyway.

Comment: @Zack: It's very close to what you have.  I had started with the 1.42 API, noticed your comments on the other answer about 1.35, and worked backwards to get this.  However, this is easier to check, e.g. if p.leaf() == "." (because p == "/some/dir/").

Comment: [`remove_leaf` is currently deprecated](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#path-deprecated-functions).

Answer (score 70):

If it's really just the file name extension you want to change then you are probably better off writing:

```
p.replace_extension(".foo");
```

for most other file path operations you can use the operators `/=` and `/` allowing to concatenate parts of a name. For instance

```
boost::filesystem::path p("c:\\dir");
p /= "subdir";
```

will refer to `c:\dir\subdir`.

Comment: I'm working with Boost 1.35 so I don't have replace_extension yet. But even so I can't see how you thought it solves my problem. I want to **append** an "extension", not change it. I illustrated this in the question, suppose `path p("c:\\dir")`, now comes something that will append `abc` to `p`, which should result in `p` pointing to `c:\dirabc`. The operator `/` also can't help with my problem.

Comment: You should have mentioned you use Boost V1.35. There you have a global function replace_extension(path) doing the same as I described above. Additionally, replace_extension simply adds an extension if none is present already. 

If you want to modify parts of your path (for instance a directory part, say c:\\dir\\bla to c:\\dirfoo\\bla) you need to take the path apart, modify the parts of the path (which are just strings) with any string function you prefer and put them together afterwards. No way around this...

Comment: It doesn't add an extension if there isn't one (atleast not in 1.35). And if there is one it will replace it for me, which is **not** what I wanted. I simply want to **append**. Follow my suggested code on how I'm solving it now to see what I want.

Comment: Although this might not be the correct answer to the question, it solved my problem for me so +1!

Answer (score 10):

With Version 3 of Filesytem library (Boost 1.55.0) it's as easy as just

```
boost::filesystem::path p("one_path");
p += "_and_another_one";
```

resulting in `p = "one_path_and_another_one"`.

Comment: But still no `operator+(std::string)` or `operator+(const char*)`. I don't know why they have to make it so difficult.

Comment: Any idea in what exact version this was added? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/release_history.html is not of any help and newer versions don't seem to exist...

Comment: Found it, it's 1.50.0: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/filesystem/doc/release_history.html

Answer (score 5):

You can define the `+` operator yourself such that you can add two `boost::filesystem::path` variables.

```
inline boost::filesystem::path operator+(boost::filesystem::path left, boost::filesystem::path right){return boost::filesystem::path(left)+=right;}
```

Then you can even add a `std::string` variable (implicit conversion). This is similar to the definition of the `operator/` from

**include/boost/filesystem/path.hpp:**

```
inline path operator/(const path& lhs, const path& rhs)  { return path(lhs) /= rhs; }
```

Here is a working example:

**main.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

using namespace boost::filesystem;
inline path operator+(path left, path right){return path(left)+=right;}

int main() {
  path p1 = "/base/path";
  path p2 = "/add/this";
  std::string extension=".ext";
  std::cout << p1+p2+extension << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

compiled with

```
g++ main.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem
```

produces the output:

```
$ ./a.out 
"/base/path/add/this.ext"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
path p;
std::string st = "yoo";
p /= st + ".foo";
```

Answer (score 0):

sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/dll.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::filesystem::path my_path("/usr/development");
    my_path /= "ControllerApp";
    std::string l1_path = my_path.string();
    std::cout << "initial path: " << l1_path << std::endl;
    my_path = my_path / boost::filesystem::path("Script") / boost::filesystem::path("latest");
    std::cout << "final path: " << my_path.string() << std::endl;
}
```

output:

> initial path: /usr/development/ControllerApp

> final path: /usr/development/ControllerApp/Script/latest

you can either append a directory to the path by using concatenation operator "**/=**".  or using "**/**" you can append multiple directories to the path. and this is the easiest platform independent path *combine/append/concatenation* mechanism provided by Boost Filesystem.