# Append string to the end of file using boost::filesystem

Tags: c++, boost

Using newer boost (1.55 for example) I can append a string to the end of path like this:

```
 fs::path binShaderPath("somedir/somefile.bin");
     binShaderPath  +="xxx";
```

In my case I use Boost 1.49 which doesn't come with such an overload.What's the workaround?

For those who are going to point me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396548/appending-to-boostfilesystempath)  answer :I don't want to append a directory or file ,just some arbitrary chars right to the end of file.

**UPDATE:**

Currently the workaround I came up with is:

```
             std::string copySrt = binShaderPath.string();
             copySrt.append(".xxx");
             binShaderPath = fs::path(copySrt);
```

It is not efficient,strings copying etc, but I found no other way around.

Comment: Would something along the lines of `fs::path(binShaderPath.file_string() + "xxx")` help?

Comment: there is no file_string().There is .string() which is const

Comment: Ah okay - thougth 1.49 would use the old filesystem interface... constness would be a problem in my snippet though since it copy-constructs anyway

Answer (score 0):

You could overload operator+= so that you get the desired result